# Select one value from table and pass it to variable - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to create variable called `$start`. As a value I want to select one value from column called `timestamp` from the last row of my table called `table_ex`. So far I have this:

```
class Main {
//some other code

function dataBaseConnect(){
           //well working part
        }

function getTimeValue(){
        $sql = "SELECT `timestamp` FROM `table_ex` WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table_ex`)";
    $this->start = $this->handler->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    }

function printVal(){
        $this->dataBaseConnect();
        $this->getTimeValue();
        $this->messOuput = "Sth text " .$this->start;
}
}
```

The problem is that variable is not getting that value I wanted. Could anyone explain me where is the problem?

Comment: The query is just a string, you exec that string why would you think that it would magically appear where you used to have a string containing a query

Comment: `SELECT timestamp FROM table_ex order by timestamp desc limit 1` ?

Comment: Also as Ram points out. Your actual query is also incorrect as it is trying to select from a column name and not a table, and could be improved on as well

Comment: if you have timestamp as a column or table?

Comment: Timestamp is a column. I just want to take last value from timestamp column and pass it to variable $start. That's all. @RamRaider whats the problem with my query actually?

Comment: See answer for whats wrong

Comment: See @RamRaider comment for a better quicker simpler way of achieving the same result

Comment: Does it work? Using `MAX` - which is one of the aggregator functions - means that the sub query must look at all records to find the max value which is not necessarily going to be that fast depending upon number of records in the table... and of course, a shas now been pointed out - `timestamp` is a column rather than a table

Comment: timestamp as column name Then how can you use (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `timestamp`). use table name not column name

Comment: Basically you are executing a query that wont work as it has a syntax error, which you are not checking for. Then you make no attempt to collect the result of the query into the variable you want to store the result into. In short its difficult to think of a polite word for _What is wrong_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for You:

```
function getTimeValue()
{
    // note the table name is now used in the inner query
    $sql = "SELECT `timestamp` FROM `table_ex` WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table_ex`)";
    $this-start = $this->handler->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}
```

Comment: You might want to sanity check that query

Comment: Why? I'm not binding nor using any variables

Comment: Hint: timestamp is a column name and not a table name or if its the other way round it still a nonsence query.

Comment: Sanity check NOT sanitize

Comment: You are right @RiggsFolly I didn't check SQL close enough. Point for You ;)

Comment: thanks, I've tried yours version but something is wrong. query is okay I think, because in sql console in phpMyAdmin I am getting proper value, but my variable $this->start is still empty. I also tried an @RamRider asnwer but instead of value from column, I got string with query.

Comment: DB credentials are ok? You can try to run some simple query to verify like `SELECT 1+1` - as You know expected result should be `2`

Comment: Now my variable is a string `SELECT 1+1` I think credentials are okay because I've got some `INSERT` queries and they are working fine.

Comment: @K.Zakrzewski I have updated my answer, exec is not returning any results, query is the method we need.

Comment: tried again and still not success, maybe cause is somewhere else?
I've updated my first post.